# Django CMS display name of model entry

Tags: python, django

I would like to have the entries for a model listed in the admin panel showing the name of the model entry. Currently it shows the following

[image]

However, instead of `Objekt object` I would like to have `Objekt OBJECT_NAME` where `OBJECT_NAME` is the name of the object. My model is the following:

models.py

```
class Objekt(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    beschreibung = models.TextField()

    aktiv = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Miet-Objekt'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Miet-Objekte'
```

and admin.py

```
class ObjektAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Objekt
    can_delete = True
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: restart dev server

Comment: Do you use Python2 or Python3? If later I think you should implement the method `__str__`.

Comment: @cezar Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Gerne ;) You should have stated which versions you use, it would have made answering easier.